# C++ Windows: LRESULT CALLBACK and WNDPROC

Tags: c++, windows, class, winapi

I have a class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        void Init ();

    private:
        LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
};
```

Also, in another file I have a function:

```
void MakeWindow (WNDPROC wnd_proc, DWORD style, HICON lg_icon, ...);
```

The first parameter is supposed to take a LRESULT CALLBACK function as input. Somewhere I also have a definition for the Init function:

```
void SomeClass::Init ()
{
    MakeWindow (this->WndProc, WM_POPUP, NULL, ...);
}
```

This gives me error C3867 in VS2012 when I try to pass `this->WndProc` to `WNDPROC wnd_proc`. Is there any way I can pass the `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc` function to `MakeWindow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `WndProc` method is an instance method and so does not match `WNDPROC`. Because it is an instance method it receives an extra, implict, `this` parameter.

You need to declare it as a `static` method in order for it to be compatible with `WNDPROC`.

Comment: Adding `static` did get rid of the error! Would adding `static` put any limitations on the function though?

Comment: Yes. It means that you cannot access any instance variables. If you need to do that you need to find a different way to connect the window to the instance. Typically by storing the instance in the window's private data.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I will mark this as the answer when I can.

Comment: @RaymondChen blogged about this very subject yesterday: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/27/10492898.aspx

Comment: @David Page not found. Updated link: [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140127-00/?p=1963](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140127-00/?p=1963)